# ExtJS 4.2.0: Ext.Direct and namespaces

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2, ext-direct

I'm just starting to look at Ext Direct, and I'm trying to get namespaces to work with it. However, I'm not having much luck.

Following the documentation (http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.direct.RemotingProvider-cfg-disableNestedActions) I tried this:

```
Ext.Direct.addProvider({
    url: 'router',
    type: 'remoting',
    actions: {
        TestAction: {
            name: 'foo',
            len:  1
        },
        'TestAction.Foo': {
            name: 'bar',
            len: 1
        }
    },
    namespace: 'MyApp'
});

MyApp.TestAction.Foo.bar();
```

However, I'm now getting the error 'object has no method bar'.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methods definitions must be array of objects, not objects.

This way, no error:

```
Ext.Direct.addProvider({
    url: 'router',
    type: 'remoting',
    actions: {
        TestAction: [{ // <= Here, array!
            name: 'foo',
            len:  1
        }],
        'TestAction.Foo': [{
            name: 'bar',
            len: 1
        }]
    },
    namespace: 'MyApp'
});
```

Comment: +1 This is correct as per the `actions` description in the Ext.direct.RemotingProvider documentation: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.direct.RemotingProvider-cfg-actions

Comment: Yes this works! It seems like in some places their documentation is not correct...